# How to append cookie value to end of response Location header with Apache?

Tags: apache, http-headers, http-redirect

I have a page that issues an HTTP redirect.  I need to append the current session id (jsessionid) to the end of the HTTP redirect to pass this id as a GET parameter in the redirect.

Can `mod_header`'s `Header append` directive pick up a cookie value via `SetEnvIf`?

Should a rewrite rather be involved?  But `mod_rewrite` just rewrites the *request* not the *response*, yes?

How would you solve this from an Apache perspective without touching back-end code?

---

Update: the Apache-JVM is handled by either mod_jk OR via IBM HTTP Server connection to WebSphere.

Comment: How do you connect to your back-end? Do you use mod_proxy/mod_jk to connect to a back-end, or is it an internal apache module like mod_python/mod_php?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to get a single cookie name/value. But you can get the full `Cookie:`-field in a `RewriteRule` using `%{HTTP_COOKIE}`. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: @Lekensteyn, I've only ever used rewrites to rewrite INCOMING requests, how can they be used to rewrite headers on responses?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As to my knowledge, with Apache HTTPd you do it like this:

```
SetEnvIf Cookie "mycookie=([^;]+)" MYCOOKIE=$1
SetEnvIf Cookie "mycookie=([^;]+)" HAVE_MYCOOKIE=1
Header add Set-Cookie "mycookie=%{MYCOOKIE}e; expires=0" env=HAVE_MYCOOKIE
```

You can also add additional cookie attributes like path and domain if you want.

Comment: Wouldn't this add the cookie to each outgoing response? Xepoch wanted it only for responses that are of redirect type.

Comment: Indeed, I have overlooked that requirement, however I don't know an immediate solution to that.